# jQuery datePicker setDate function blanks the input field when input field is inside a <form> element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

Fanrod here. It's my first time so be gentle with me.

See the code below. It should just work, yes? When you click the button the input field should display today's date but today's date just flashes up for a second then the box goes blank.

If you remove the FORM tags then it works as expected.

So setDate() doesn't work if the input field is inside a FORM element.

Have tried this under Firefox and Chrome and get the same result.

Am I abusing datePicker?

Have scoured stackoverflow, experts exchange, etc. for a resolution but no joy.

I can't believe this is a bug because datePicker is so widely used but I can't see any other conclusion.

The only work-arounds I can see are to either never have the input field inside a FORM (feasible in my case but worrying for the future) or to use $("#ttdateofbirth').val(...) with obvious drawbacks.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thank you for your input.

Non-working web-page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>DatePicker test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/js/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/js/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
.datepicker {
    font: 11pt "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
    margin: 10px;
}
.inputlabel {
    font: 11pt "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
    margin: 3px;
    float:left; clear:left;
    display: block;
}

.ui-datepicker { font-size: 8pt !important; background: #cccccc; }

input {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: .25em;
    font: 11pt "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
    margin: 3px;
    }
button {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: .25em;
    font: 11pt "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
    margin: 3px;
    }

</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
// set up inputs for dates before today's date
$(function(){
    var pickerOpts = {
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/y",
        showButtonPanel: true,
        changeYear: true,
        changeMonth : true
        };
        $("#ttdateofbirth").datepicker(pickerOpts);
        });

    function setthedate() {
        var adate = new Date();
        $("#ttdateofbirth").datepicker('setDate',adate);
        };
//]]>
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form>
<span class="inputlabel">Date of birth:</span>
<span><input id="ttdateofbirth" type="text"  value=""/>
<button style="float:left;display:inline;" onclick="setthedate()">Set date</button>
</span>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So your form is submitting after you selecting the date ..pressing enter on date picker to select date ??

Comment: Is it submitting after you select the date? I don't understand. Are you asking me or telling me? The problem I want to solve has nothing to with the user selecting a date from the pop-up date-picker window or typing characters into the ttdateofbirth field. The problem occurs when the setthedate() function is invoked.

Comment: i am just asking ..As per you explanation i'm understood that the form is submitting

Comment: It's in the line $("#ttdateofbirth").datepicker('setDate',adate); - that's how you invoke a datepicker method.

Comment: still you are not aware of form submission ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a `<button>` element inside a form, it submits the form, reloading the page and emptying the inputs. Change it to:

```
<input type="button" style="float:left;display:inline;" onclick="setthedate()" value="Set date">
```

or use return false / preventDefault.

Comment: if he write onclick="setthedate()"  .after that if he wants to submit which one he has to click???

Comment: Adeneo: that works. It was all about the button action. Thank you very much!